# Linux Bashrc Nexted For Loops

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Below is my code, I have two arrays...array and array2.

```
#!/bin/bash

array = (1 3 5 7 9)
array2 = (2 4 6 8 A)

for i in "${array[@]}" 
do
  echo $i
  for i in "${array2[@]}" 
  do 
    echo $i
  done
done
```

I want to have the following output echoed out onto my console when I run my script:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
A
```

But instead I get the following:

```
1
2
4
6
8
A
3
2
4
6
8
A
5
2
4
6
8
A
7
2
4
6
8
A
9
2
4
6
8
A
```

I'm really trying to accomplish the following through nested loops like in C/C++:

```
char array[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
char array2[5] = {2, 4, 6, 8, A};

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
  std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
  std::cout << array2[i] << std::endl;  
}
```

But how can I use the same iterator var i to control two different arrays?

Comment: There's no nested loop in your c++ example, so why do you think you need one in a bash script?

Comment: Just a note: There is a couple of syntax errors when initiating the arrays (spaces around `=`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the indices instead of the elements:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(1 3 5 7 9)
array2=(2 4 6 8 A)

for i in "${!array[@]}" 
do
  echo "${array[i]}"
  echo "${array2[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The more or less exact transcription of the c++ code would be

```
for i in {0..5}
do
  echo ${array[$i]}
  echo ${array2[$i]}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another algorithm, you can repeatedly print the first element of each array and pop them until the first is empty:

```
array=(1 3 5 7 9)
array2=(2 4 6 8 A)

while [ -n "$array" ]
do
    echo ${array[0]}
    echo ${array2[0]}
    array=("${array[@]:1}")
    array2=("${array2[@]:1}")
done
```

edit: This does destroy the arrays as you go, so only use it if you don't care about the arrays existing after the loop.

Comment: Why are you destroying the arrays in the process of simply iterating over them?

Comment: That's a good point.  I was assuming that OP was building the arrays specifically for this purpose.  I'll put a disclaimer in the answer.